# How to test Enhanced Recurring Payments Standard on the new Paypal Sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, recurring

I have a test environment for my website that I normally use the Paypal Sandbox on to test transactions before going live. I would like to test the Enhanced Recurring Payments feature, but I can't find the option to do so (the links to add more features direct me to the live site), and nothing I've found on Google has given an answer on how to test Enhanced Recurring Payments on Paypal Sandbox since it's been changed.

Is ERP supported on Paypal Sandbox, or do I just not know how to access this option? Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sign up in the sandbox here: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_product-go&product=premium_services

(for the curious, I got this URL by going to paypal.com/erp and then adding "sandbox." in front of the resulting URL's paypal.com)

Log in with your test account email/password (something like aaaaaa_############_biz@emaildomain.com  )

If it says "Please login to use the PayPal Sandbox features.", that's an issue with the new sandbox that's being worked on--for now, clear all your paypal.com cookies , log in to developer.paypal.com again, and then visit the above URL again

Comment: I took your advice, and it worked. Thank you. The only thing I would add is that anyone who wants to try this needs to use a Paypal Sandbox Personal, not Business, account. The Paypal Sandbox will ask you to upgrade your test Personal account to a test Business account (with ERP), and so will not work if you're using a test Business account.