# Enhanced Recurring Payments sandbox business account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

How to turn on Enhanced Recurring Payments  for sandbox business account? I tried [How to enable recurring payments for sandbox account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848191/how-to-enable-recurring-payments-for-sandbox-account), but i don't have Financial Information column in my profile section. [How to test Enhanced Recurring Payments Standard on the new Paypal Sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348548/how-to-test-enhanced-recurring-payments-standard-on-the-new-paypal-sandbox) also doesn't help - have an Message 3005 error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the solution but please do check out this link, guess itss related to sandbox errors http://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/227988-paypal-ipn-sandbox-error-3005/

And would suggest you to look for better recurring systems than Paypal.